# removing factor levels using subset

Tags: r

In the following data frame:

```
x <-c(rep (c ("s1", "s2", "s3"),each=5 ))
y <- c(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 3) )               
z<-c(1:15)    

x_name <- "dimensions"
y_name <- "aspects"
z_name<-"value"
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
names(df) <- c(x_name,y_name, z_name)
```

I would like to remove factor levels 'a' and 'b' from 'aspects'. When I try

```
df1<-subset(df, aspects !="a")
```

it works ok.
However,

```
df1<-subset(df, aspects != c("a", "b"))
```

removes not all but just some of 'a' and 'b' and gives a warning :

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.
```

Can you help me figure out what is wrong? Is there a way to use `subset` to remove 'a' and 'b' in one go?

Comment: have a look at `%in%`. here, you're asking R to compare `aspects` to the vector `c("a", "b")`, elementwise (`aspects` must not be of length 2, hence the warning). So what you are looking for is `subset(df, !aspects %in% c("a", "b"))`

Comment: For fun: `"%out%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) == 0; subset(df, aspects %out% c("a", "b"))`.

Comment: David I edited it. I think it is a different question now from what you pointed to.

Comment: @Vasile  The accepted answer is what you need to follow, as pointed out in CathG's comment.